# Ssh-agent step using the wrong working dir

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Suddenly, without any pipeline changes, the wrong workingdir is used by the ssh-agent plugin. I use this in the deployment step to rsync files into the test-server environment.

```
[project@2] Running shell script <-- build step
[project@2] Running shell script <-- test step
[project] Running shell script <-- deployment step
```

As you can see above the wrong working dir (without @2) is used for deployment without the build from previous steps.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'composer:latest'
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'composer install --ignore-platform-reqs'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'php:7.1.13-cli'
        }        
      }
      steps {
        sh './vendor/bin/phpunit'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sshagent (credentials: ['PROJECT_KEY']) {
          sh 'rsync \
                -a \
                --delete \
                --exclude="*local.php" \
                --exclude=".*" \
                --include="config/***" \
                --include="module/***" \
                --include="vendor/***" \
                --include="shell/***" \
                --include="bin/***" \
                --include="init_autoloader.php" \
                --exclude="*" \
                -e "ssh -p 2222" \
                . username@*****.com:/data/sites/test.*****.com/'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to identify the [agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) for your last stage. You can run your pipeline on one `agent`. In this case identify `agent at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! I added "agent any" and now it works.. I thought the "agent any" on line 2 was the default for each stage. This Jenkinsfile did work before without that agent declaration.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe Jenkins accidentally got on the same agent. FYI: don't forget about `node`